# MySQL no inicia con xamp

Tags: mysql, xampp, servicio

Hola no puedo iniciar el servicio de MySQL en xampp ya realize el cambio de archivos de la carpeta Backup a la carpeta data

El error:

```
10:10:24 a. m.  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:10:24 a. m.  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:10:24 a. m.  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:10:24 a. m.  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:10:24 a. m.  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:10:24 a. m.  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
10:10:24 a. m.  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

el archivo log marca esto:

```
Cannot find checkpoint record at LSN (1,0x570a)
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [ERROR] mysqld.exe: Aria recovery failed. Please run aria_chk -r 
on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked 
 functions
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, 
instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 
12 
MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 
MB.
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 59715897; 
transaction id 5087
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from 
C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 220428 10:10:18
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not 
loaded
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2022-04-28 10:10:18 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Es la primer ves que me sucede este inconveniente, agradezco mucho su apoyo

Comment: BUsca en `C:\xampp\mysql\` los archivos ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 y aria_log_control, y bórralos (muévelos a otro lado por si acaso). Prueba de nuevo

Comment: Puede que los archivos que te dice @Alfabravo estén en la ruta `/xampp/mysql/data/` y los archivos a borrar son los que se llamen así `aria_log.########`, donde `#` serán números. Eso es lo que dice el mensaje: *`Please run aria_chk -r 
on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files`*. En vez de borrarlos, muévelos a otra parte, por si acaso.

Comment: @A.Cedano en efecto si son esos archivos que comenta Alfabravo muchísimas garcias a los dos!!!

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias!

Comment: Si tu BD está en producción y no tienes una política de backups, piensa en ello seriamente, no sea que te quedes en blanco cualquier día de estos sin poder recuperar los datos.

Comment: Bueh, ahí quedó la respuesta con lo que se comentó por acá :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Busca en la ruta `C:\xampp\mysql` los archivos

```
ib_logfile0, 
ib_logfile1 
aria_log_control
```

y bórralos (muévelos a otro lado por si acaso, mejor). Prueba de nuevo.

Puede que los archivos estén en la ruta `/xampp/mysql/data/` y los archivos a borrar son los que se llamen así `aria_log.########`, donde # serán números. Eso es lo que dice el mensaje: `Please run aria_chk -r  on all Aria tables and delete all aria_log.######## files`